# Using .position with css position: relative not working as expected

Tags: javascript, css

I have a menu that's not working right. have a look at this code: http://jsfiddle.net/PX9nU/1/

On `#menu li`, if I leave `position: relative` in place, the console records a left of 0 across all menu items when you hover. If I remove `position: relative`, it records the expected correct left value for each item.

I need the `position: relative` in place for the submenu to format correctly, but I need the left value to output correctly for some animation I'm trying to achieve.

-Why is the left not returning the expected value with `position: relative` in place?

-Is there another way to get the left value for each item as they are hovered over?

Comment: What exactly is the expected value? If you set position: relative (or any position for that matter) top and left default to 0 until you set them otherwise. In the link you provided, you didn't set the left or top property for any elements.

Comment: try using the .Offset() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your jQuery selector. You're selecting with `$('#menu li .item')`, which gives you back the link elements. Calling `position()` on those gives their position within their parent element, the enclosing LI, which is 0,0 in each case. I think you want the position of the enclosing LI within its UL, which you can get this way:

```
p = $(this).parent().position();
```